# Tuleap - Change weekdays in Agile Dashboard

Tags: tuleap

Is there any way to change the weekdays to Sunday-Thursday rather than Monday-Friday on the Agile Dashboard (so that sprint duration is calculated accordingly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported yet (I'm developer of Tuleap). But it's requested time to time, so it might appear someday (if someone decide to implement or pay for it).

Comment: Your answer popped up in the [LQP review queue](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/577622).  I was going to suggest adding a supporting citation, then noticed that you might be considered an "expert witness".  It would be REALLY useful context if you edit the answer to disclose how you come to know this information.  :-)

Comment: I added some info, I don't know what is the policy on SO how to present those things. Let me know if there is something I can improve.